Add a separator only if there is more than one element
I have a todo list that I made with the help of Pranav Rustagi and Twisty. I still have a problem for which I can't find a solution.
Between each text added, I want to add a separator (pipe). My problem is that when I delete the first element, the next element, which becomes the first one, has an unwanted pipe.
So how can I add a separator only if there is more than one element, and only if it's not the first element ?
To reproduce the scenario: add a, b, c, and then delete a. You'll see the pipe before the b still there. Is it better to imagine a pipe only if there is an element after?
One main issue here is the empty() inside the remove function. It doesn't delete the span.output from the DOM so I cannot use first() or do something in css like :
.output:not(:first-of-type):before {
  content:'|';
  padding:0 5px;
}

I can't use remove() instead of empty() either because I won't be able to add a line again if I delete them all.
Any help would be appreciated.


$(function() {
  $(".container").on('input', 'input[type=text]', function(event) {
    var i = $(this).closest(".flex-row").index();
    var v = (i == 0) ? $(this).val() : "|" + $(this).val();
    $("#custom_wrapper .output").eq(i).html(v);
  });

  $('.add').click(function() {
    var count = $("input").length;
    count++;
    var row = $("<div>", {
      class: "flex-row"
    }).insertBefore(this);
    $("<label>").appendTo(row);
    $("<input>", {
      type: "text",
      class: "input",
      id: "custom-text-" + count,
      placeholder: "custom text " + count,
      tabindex: count
    }).appendTo($("label", row));
    $("<button>", {
      class: "remove"
    }).html("-").appendTo(row);
    $("<span>", {
      class: "output",
      dataid: "custom-text-" + count
    }).insertAfter($("#custom_wrapper .output:last"));
  });

  $('body').on('click', '.remove', function() {
    $(this).parent('.flex-row').remove();
    var j = $(this).parent().find('.input').attr("id");
    $('#custom_wrapper .output[dataid="' + j + '"').empty();
  })
})
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <article>
      <section>
        <div class="flex-row">
          <label
            ><input
              class="input"
              type="text"
              name=""
              id="custom-text-1"
              placeholder="custom text"
              tabindex="1" /></label
          ><button class="remove">-</button>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-row">
          <label
            ><input
              class="input"
              type="text"
              name=""
              id="custom-text-2"
              placeholder="custom text 2"
              tabindex="2" /></label
          ><button class="remove">-</button>
        </div>
        <button class="add">+</button>
        <div class="flex-row">
          <div class="token">
            {{customText[<span id="custom_wrapper"><span class="output" dataid="custom-text-1"></span><span class="output" dataid="custom-text-2"></span></span>]}}
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>



I also tried to add the pipe with css instead, the part that changes in the jquery is the following:
 $(".container").on('input', 'input[type=text]', function(event) {
    var i = $(this).closest(".flex-row").index();
    v=$(this).val();
    $("#custom_wrapper .output").eq(i).html(v);
  });

I reformulated my delete function to delete instead of emptying
$('body').on('click', '.remove', function() {
const i = $(this).closest(".flex-row").index();
$("#custom_wrapper .output").eq(i).remove();
$(this).parent('.flex-row').remove();
 })

Final code looks like this :


<html><head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
  $(".container").on('input', 'input[type=text]', function(event) {
    var i = $(this).closest(".flex-row").index();
    // var v = (i == 0) ? $(this).val() : "|" + $(this).val();
    v=$(this).val();
    $("#custom_wrapper .output").eq(i).html(v);
  });

  $('.add').click(function() {
    var count = $("input").length;
    count++;
    var row = $("<div>", {
      class: "flex-row"
    }).insertBefore(this);
    
    $("<label>").appendTo(row);
    
    $("<input>", {
      type: "text",
      class: "input",
      placeholder: "custom text " + count,
      tabindex: count
    }).appendTo($("label", row));
    
    $("<button>", {
      class: "remove"
    }).html("-").appendTo(row);
    
    $("<span>", {
      class: "output"
    }).appendTo($("#custom_wrapper"));
  });

  $('body').on('click', '.remove', function() {
    const i = $(this).closest(".flex-row").index();
    $("#custom_wrapper .output").eq(i).remove();
    $(this).parent('.flex-row').remove();
  })
});

</script>
<style>
.output:not(:first-child):before{
content:'|';
}

</style>
 </head>

    <body>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <article>
      <section>
        <div class="flex-row">
          <label for="custom-text-1"><span class="visually-hidden">Custom Text 1</span><input class="input" type="text" id="custom-text-1" placeholder="custom text" tabindex="1" /></label><button class="remove">-</button>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-row">
          <label for="custom-text-2"><span class="visually-hidden">Custom Text 2</span><input class="input" type="text" id="custom-text-2" placeholder="custom text 2" tabindex="2"></label><button class="remove">-</button>
        </div>
        <button class="add">+</button>
        <div class="flex-row">
          <div>customText{{[<span id="custom_wrapper"><span class="output"></span><span class="output"></span></span>]}}</div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>


</body>



It works, but this solution doesn't suit me: I use a copy function to copy and paste the exit code, and when I copy and paste, the separators are not there, because they are added as pseudo-elements, and seem not to be present in the DOM.
So I definitely need a jquery/javascript solution that actually adds these pipes...

$('input').length will tell you how many inputs you have. However, it's not clear to me whether you expect the | based on the number of inputs, or which inputs have values.  So you may need to verify whether the input is empty when counting the number of inputs.

"I can't use remove() instead of empty() either because I won't be able to add a line again if I delete them all." - why not?

Might make more sense, if you rebuilt the output completely every time:
  $(".container").on('input', 'input[type=text]', function(event) {
    var values = [];
    $(this).closest('section').find('input[type=text]').each(function() {
      values.push($('<span class="output"></span>').text($(this).val()).html());
    });
    $("#custom_wrapper").html(values.join('|'));
  });

- loop over all the input fields, get their value wrapped into a span - and then finally join the whole array together with a pipe symbol. (And the CSS that added it as a pseudo element, needs to be removed.)
And your function that removes a field, needs to trigger the input event on the first field left, to update the output - or simply clear the wrapper content, if there are no fields left:
  $('body').on('click', '.remove', function() {
    const i = $(this).closest(".flex-row").index();
    $(this).parent('.flex-row').remove();
    if($('.container input[type=text]').length) {
      $('.container input[type=text]').eq(0).trigger('input');
    } else {
      $('#custom_wrapper').html('');
    }
  });


thanks C3roe, looks perfect but yes, the user can remove all field, so maybe this is not the solution. (but thanks for sharing this)

@blogob then just trigger the input event if there is a field left, and else just clear the container of all content - see edit.

there is strange things happening, like the span.output is nowhere in the DOM..anyway, you solved my problem, thak you very very much C3roe !!

I think what you're trying achieve can simply be done by using CSS only.


.container span:after {
  content: '|';
  margin: 0 2px;
}

.container span:last-child:after {
  content: '';
  margin: 0 2px;
}
<div class='container'>
  <span>a</span>
  <span>b</span>
  <span>c</span>
</div>

<div class='container'>
  <span>a</span>
</div>




Hi Naeem, technically yes, as I said in my question, I tried that and it works, except if you want to copy paste the code..Copy won't work with pseudo elements..

hey @DarkBee, how did you do that? Thanks.

I've been told to create a "runnable" example with "Stack Snippets". How do I do that?
